# VBA not working in Excel for Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel-2011

I bought a Macbook Pro and Office 2011. Am trying to use an Excel file with VBA code and macros, which works on every other Windows PC I've tried. Unfortunately it doesn't on my Mac. Office 2011 is up-to-date, macros enabled - should be no problem.

Got any suggestion what to check?
Is there any specific guidance for VBA writers about the differences and specifics of VBA in Office 2011 on MAC?

Comment: I agree with Portland Runner, but for the sake of providing some amount of help... What happens?  Does it throw an error?  Does it do nothing?  If you open the VBA editor, is there code?  Can you step through it successfully?  Perhaps the button or event isn't firing, but the code is okay.

Comment: To answer your question about the differences, [the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597509%28v=office.14%29.aspx) lumps Office 2010 and Office for Mac 2011 together.  [This question](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword/vba-support-on-office-mac/5023cdbc-fadf-4e39-a49f-59d2534aef85) on Microsoft Answers has dead links to Mac-specific documentation.